# Sharing in development Ruby Gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

We use Rails for the majority of our web projects and in a lot of cases we share code we have as dependancies such as our API as Gems. We also have some projects which are similar in nature enough that we've built Engines and then have host applications that use these.

These are all hosted on our own servers and we share the Gems with the projects using Gem In A Box (this is because we can't upload the Gems to anywhere else due to security restrictions). During development we comment out the lines to reference either a specific version on our server or our local version if we are developing within the Gem itself.

So for example:

```
# version on the server
gem 'our_gem', '1.1.0', source: 'https://gems.domain.net'
# local version
gem 'our_gem', path: '../our_gem'
```

What happens is that when we do a build on our CI server we then have a script that reads through the Gemfile and finds any gems that have our server as the source and then vendorize them and reference them as the vendored path.

For example:

```
# this
gem 'our_gem', '1.1.0', source: 'https://gems.domain.net'
# becomes this
gem 'our_gem', path: 'vendor/gems/our_gem-1.1.0'
```

However the problem we have encountered is that when we are in development and we may have several features or bugs we want to push to our QA team to start testing it means we have to bump the version each time so we can reference it in our Gemfile's as a dependancy. We can't reference the branch due to the Git repository not accessible to our build setup and some other restrictions.

How do teams usually handle in-development dependancies that don't have a version yet? We've thought about having a development version of Gem In A Box and then not passing a version to it in our Gemfile...

```
# shared dev version of gem on our dev gem server
gem 'our_gem', source: 'https://dev.gems.domain.net'
```

But the problem here is that we still need to up the version every time in order to push to the Gem Server. Is there a standard way to push a package to a Package Manager whereby the version is always the same (or better yet is version-less but hosted by the manager)?

We also have the same issue with NPM (we run a local version of Vedaccio).

Comment: I would try to avoid having dependencies which are different with the same version number.

Is this a use case for `~>` in the Gemfile? for example `~> 2.1` will get all versions `>= 2.1` and `< 3.0`. You can continue to develop the gem as version 2.x.x and your app will consume the latest version, but then it is important that gems that don't pass the QA process don't get promoted to your source of released gems.

Comment: No it's more about having a gem stored somewhere that's sharable to other team members and the build server on bundle install that doesn't have a new version yet as it's not a final release. The pessimistic operator is when you want to restrict the version but within a reasonable set of rules e.g. allow patches.

Comment: Ideally the gem can be tested in isolation before packaging it and deploying it as an artifact. As you said, maybe you need a dev repository as a staging environment and the gems versions that make it through the next QA process get promoted to the release repository.